# Which is the best practice to add a related objects in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, code-first

I recently created a Web API project in .NET Core 3.1 and I implemented Entity Framework Core using *code first* approach. Each of my models refer to others like this:

```
public class Condominium
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public int Levels { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public CondominiumType CondominiumType { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see in this example I am referring to Address and to CondominiumType without using reference Id. Entity Framework will create the corresponding foreign keys when the database will be migrated.

This works perfectly fine when I have to add a new Condominium with a new Address but i am facing an issue when I want to add an **existing** Address or Condominium Type.

When I pass an object to the context with an Id that has already been added to the database the program throws an exception because i'm violating the UNIQUE constraint of the table. I know that I can fix this problem by adding reference keys writing something like this

```
    public class Condominium
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public int Levels { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int CondominiumTypeId { get; set; }
    public CondominiumType CondominiumType { get; set; }

}
```

BUT I'm wondering which will be the proper way to resolve cases like this. **¿Is It Possible to add existing objects without rewriting my classes?**

In the business Layer i'm passing the data throw an UnitOfWork Patter:

```
 public async Task<bool> AddCondominium(int AgencyId,CondominiumDTO newCondominium)
    {
        var condominium = _mapper.Map<Condominium>(newCondominium);
        condominium.ConsortiumAdministrationAgency = new ConsortiumAdministrationAgency() { Id = AgencyId };
        _unitOfWork.Addresses.Add(condominium.Address);
        _unitOfWork.Condominiums.Add(condominium);
        return await _unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();
    }
```

Comment: What you're asking is how to solve a symptom of the problem.. Instead, you should ask, how to solve the cause of the problem. The proper way, would be to retrieve the 'duplicate' entity from the database, update whatever property has changed, and then save the changes.

Comment: I don't believe this problem has anything to do with your classes but the way you are accessing your entities within your context. Can you add the code where you access this context that is causing the issue. As stated above you should be referencing your existing entity within the context and then assign it to your new entity within the same context. Then when you save changes EF knows you are referencing an existing entity not trying to add a new one.

Comment: @Selthien this is the code of the service Layer: public async Task<bool> AddCondominium(int AgencyId,CondominiumDTO newCondominium)
        {
            var condominium = _mapper.Map<Condominium>(newCondominium);
            condominium.ConsortiumAdministrationAgency = new ConsortiumAdministrationAgency() { Id = AgencyId };
            _unitOfWork.Addresses.Add(condominium.Address);
            _unitOfWork.Condominiums.Add(condominium);
            return await _unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();
        }

Comment: For new entries your unique (id) should be autogenerated (not set by yourself). To update an entry you should get it by id and modify the other props and save.  In addition it can be a problem with your classes. Provide more info for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EntityFramework has to know if the object you have added to the context should be a new entity in the database or represent an already existing entity (with an Id). When you use the `Add()` method you are saying that this object is for a new row/entity. But this means that it tries to add the new entity with the values in the object. When it has the `Id` property set (which is the primary key) it tries to add the new row with that id, which will fail with a duplicate key constraint violation.

There are several solutions. You can get the object you want to reference from the context you are using. When you use something like

```
 Address address = _context.Addresses.Single(it => it.Id == someId);
```

you can use the `address` reference everywhere in your other entity classes to reference the existing entity from the database. This way, the object in `address` is in the state of "tracked" or "attached" to the context of EntityFramework. The EntityFramework will not try to add it as a new row when you run `SaveChanges()` but rather send `UPDATE` queries when you change a value (if any).

The other way is to attach the address with the `Attach()` method instead of `Add()` to the context. That way the context of EntityFramework put the object in the "tracked" or "attached" state and will not try to add it as a new row when you run `SaveChanges()` and assumes it is a entity from the database without running a `SELECT` query from the database.

Comment: it works using `single` but i am concerned about efficiency. In this example this model has 3 different entities, this means **at least 4 queries** are executed in the database to make a simple add operation. So i implemented the `attach` method and it was better in terms of performance, but now i have to manually set if i want to add a new entity or not

Comment: @OmarChahdi Check the Id. If it has one then you know it must exists before hand and you can use `Attach()`.